# Bloqueo en IRQHandler

Tags: c++, arm

Tengo un problema que no consigo entender.
Estoy desarrollando bajo IAR workbench en un STM32F407.
La estructura de mi software es en el main se comprueban un par de pines del micro y en función de cual este en activo ejecuto una clase u otra.
Si no hay ningún pin activo me quedo en bucle infinito hasta recibir una interrupción por alguno de dichos pines.
El problema es el siguiente, si al iniciar alguno de los pines está activo, no hay ningún problema, todo funciona como debe. Pero si no hay ningún pin activo y entro en bucle infinito, cuando recibo la interrupción y ejecuto la clase pertinente la función "TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler" no vuelve a ser llamada nunca, por lo que la función HAL_GetTick() siempre devuelve el mismo valor, o lo que es lo mismo, el tiempo se detiene.

```
    /* Includes    ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #include "main.h"
    #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "opt2.hpp"
    #include "opt1.hpp"

    /* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c2;
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c3;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart6;


/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USART6_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C3_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C2_Init(void);
static void MX_NVIC_Init(void);


int main(void)
{

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_USART6_UART_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_I2C3_Init();
  MX_I2C2_Init();

  /* Initialize interrupts */
  MX_NVIC_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
       if(!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Flag_1_GPIO_Port, Flag_1_Pin) && HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(flag_2_GPIO_Port, flag_2_Pin)){opt1::Get()->opt1_init();}
  else if( HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Flag_1_GPIO_Port, Flag_1_Pin) && !HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(flag_2_GPIO_Port, flag_2_Pin)){opt2::Get()->opt2_Init();}
  /* USER CODE END 2 */



  while (1)
  {

   printf("Flag: %d %d\n",HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Flag_1_GPIO_Port, Flag_1_Pin),HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(flag_2_GPIO_Port, flag_2_Pin));

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 168;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler((char*)__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler((char*)__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}


void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  switch(GPIO_Pin){
    case Flag_1_Pin:
      if(!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Flag_1_GPIO_Port, Flag_1_Pin) && HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(flag_2_GPIO_Port, flag_2_Pin)){
        printf("Entro en opt1 \n");
        OPT1::Get()->opt1_init();
      }
      break;
    case flag_2_Pin:
      if( HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Flag_1_GPIO_Port, Flag_1_Pin) && !HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(flag_2_GPIO_Port, flag_2_Pin)){
        printf("Entro en opt2 \n");
        OPT2::Get()->opt2_Init();
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  } 
}



/**
  * @brief NVIC Configuration.
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_NVIC_Init(void)
{
  /* EXTI15_10_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);
  /* EXTI9_5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);
}

/* I2C1 init function */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler((char*)__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* I2C2 init function */
static void MX_I2C2_Init(void)
{

  hi2c2.Instance = I2C2;
  hi2c2.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c2.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c2.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c2.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c2.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c2.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler((char*)__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* I2C3 init function */
static void MX_I2C3_Init(void)
{

  hi2c3.Instance = I2C3;
  hi2c3.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c3.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c3.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c3.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c3.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c3.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler((char*)__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* USART1 init function */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler((char*)__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* USART2 init function */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler((char*)__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* USART3 init function */
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart3.Instance = USART3;
  huart3.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart3.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart3.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart3.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart3.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart3.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart3.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler((char*)__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* USART6 init function */
static void MX_USART6_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart6.Instance = USART6;
  huart6.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart6.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart6.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart6.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart6.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart6.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart6.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler((char*)__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
        * Free pins are configured automatically as Analog (this feature is enabled through 
        * the Code Generation settings)
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PE2 PE3 PE4 PE5 
                           PE6 PE7 PE8 PE10 
                           PE11 PE12 PE13 PE14 
                           PE15 PE0 PE1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5 
                          |GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_10 
                          |GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14 
                          |GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC13 PC14 PC15 PC0 
                           PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 
                           PC5 PC8 PC10 PC11 
                           PC12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_0 
                          |GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4 
                          |GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11 
                          |GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA1 PA4 PA5 PA6 
                           PA7 PA11 PA12 PA15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6 
                          |GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB0 PB1 PB2 PB3 
                           PB4 PB8 PB9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3 
                          |GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);


    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Flag_1_Pin | flag_2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode =   GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD10 PD11 PD12 PD13 
                           PD14 PD15 PD0 PD1 
                           PD2 PD3 PD4 PD5 
                           PD6 PD7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13 
                          |GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1 
                          |GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5 
                          |GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}


void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{

  if (htim->Instance == TIM1) {
    HAL_IncTick();
  }

}


void _Error_Handler(char *file, int line)
{

  while(1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}
```

Comment: Si no puedes poner un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema va a ser dificil darte una respuesta. No creo que el problema sea dependiente del micro ni de si compruebas pines, eso debería ayudarte a acotar el origen del problema

Comment: Añadido el codigo completo de main.c

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. El problema es que la prioridad de las interrupciones externas es la misma que la de sistema, por tanto, al producirse una interrupción externa bloqueaba las interrupciones de sistema. Como la prioridad de la interrupción de sistema es 0 me ha bastado con poner a 1 la prioridad de las interrupciones externas.

```
static void MX_NVIC_Init(void)
{
  /* EXTI15_10_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, **1**, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);
  /* EXTI9_5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, **1**, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53903790